# how to keep static footer in buildfire, while user redirecting from one page to another in buildfire, Only loader is displayed when page will load

Tags: interface-builder, buildfire

We have to show fix footer section, while user redirecting from one page to another page. It only shows loader.

https://prnt.sc/ir3iif

Or Need to create any plugin/instance for footer section, after creating footer instance can we call footer plugin in every instances..?

Answer (score 0):

There is a footer menu in BuildFire.  Menu > Design > Footer Menu. Its different from the app's side menu. It not only looks different but also links Action Items and not just plugins. Action Items enable you to link to a variety of different actions such as linking to app content, websites, phone numbers, and more.